# rvest package read_html() function stops reading at "<" symbol

Tags: html, r, html-parsing, rvest

I was wondering if this behavior is intentional in the `rvest` package. When `rvest` sees the `<` character it stops reading the HTML.

```
library(rvest)
read_html("<html><title>under 30 years = < 30 years <title></html>")
```

Prints:

```
[1] <head>\n  <title>under 30 = </title>\n</head>
```

If this is intentional, is there a workaround?

Comment: The workaround is to stop using invalid HTML.

Comment: You don't always get to pick the HTML that you are reading.

Comment: Sure, and that’s why rvest doesn’t fail on the faulty snippet but produces a best guess. Browsers do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is normal for `rvest` because it's normal for html.

See the [w3schools HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) page.  `<` and `>` are reserved characters in html and their literal values have to be written another way, as specific character entities. Here is the entity table from the linked page, giving some commonly used html characters and their respective html entities.

```
XML::readHTMLTable("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp", which = 2)
#    Result          Description Entity Name Entity Number
# 1           non-breaking space      &nbsp;        &#160;
# 2       <            less than        &lt;         &#60;
# 3       >         greater than        &gt;         &#62;
# 4       &            ampersand       &amp;         &#38;
# 5       ¢                 cent      &cent;        &#162;
# 6       £                pound     &pound;        &#163;
# 7       ¥                  yen       &yen;        &#165;
# 8       €                 euro      &euro;       &#8364;
# 9       ©            copyright      &copy;        &#169;
# 10      ® registered trademark       &reg;        &#174;
```

So you will have to replace those values, perhaps with `gsub()` or manually if there aren't too many.  You can see that it will parse properly when those characters are replaced with the correct entity.

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("<html><title>under 30 years = &lt; 30 years </title></html>")
xmlValue(doc["//title"][[1]])
# [1] "under 30 years = < 30 years "
```

You could use `gsub()`, something like the following

```
txt <- "<html><title>under 30 years = < 30 years </title></html>"
xmlValue(htmlParse(gsub(" < ", " &lt; ", txt, fixed = TRUE))["//title"][[1]])
# [1] "under 30 years = < 30 years "
```

I used the *XML* package here, but the same applies for other packages that process html.

Comment: `rvest` is now based on `xml2` not on `xml`.