# Error reading in XML file for special character parsing

Tags: xml, r

I am currently reading through a folder of static XML files (thousands of them).

Most of them were formatted correctly, but there are some special characters that I'd like to mask. As an example, one XML file has the invalid XML code as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <INQUIRY version="4.0">
        <AUTHENTICATION>
            <LICENSEKEY>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</LICENSEKEY> 
            <PASSWORD>YYYYYYYYYYY</PASSWORD> 
        </AUTHENTICATION>
        <QUERY>
            <TRACKID>1-1-1</TRACKID> 
            <TYPE>VALID</TYPE>
            <CHANNEL>INTERNET</CHANNEL>
            <INQUIRYTYPE>O</INQUIRYTYPE>
            <DATA>
                <NAME>BARNES & NOBLE</NAME>
            </DATA>
        </QUERY>
    </INQUIRY>
```

I attempt to swap out the & with the code:

```
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)

location <- "C:/Users/Desktop/temp"
filenames=dir(location)

for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
   tmp <- gsub("&", "&amp;", readLines(paste0(location,"/",filenames[i])))
   data <- xmlParse(tmp)
   TMP<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(data,"//DATA"))
   DATAX_DF<-rbind(TMP,DATAX_DF)
}
```

Resulting in the following:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(paste0(location, "/", filenames[i])) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:/Users/Desktop/tmp/1-1-1_req.XML'
```

What is another work around to replace the ampersand and/or any ideas on why it reads the final line as incomplete so that I don't receive warnings?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447676/rvest-package-read-html-function-stops-reading-at-symbol/33447817#33447817

Comment: That's an invalid XML file. You can test it with a [validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/). How is that file being generated in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I parsed down the XML quickly to remove sensitive information. Assume that it is a valid XML file. The work-around does work, it just throws warnings on an incomplete final line.

Comment: We can't just assume that it's valid because the error you are getting clearly indicates it's not. If your XML file has an unescaped ampersand, then it's not a valid XML file, it's just a file that kind of looks like XML. You should figure out why the invalid file is being created that way in the first place. The message about the final line being incomplete is just a warning. It just means there's no new-line character at the end of the line. That's not really an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the XML needs an **&** instead of & as per  **[Section 4.6 Predefined Entities.of Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)**

An xml validator can be found here [w3schools xml validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

```
<DATA>
     <NAME>BARNES &amp; NOBLE</NAME>
</DATA>
```

Secondly the variable DF. I'm not sure DF can be bound to a data set if its empty(first call)?

This works

Two identical xml files as per above with fix (As described above)

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){ 
    data <- xmlParse(paste0(location,"/",filenames[i]))   
    TMP<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(data,"//DATA")) 
    if (i==1) {   
        DF<-TMP 
    } else { 
        DF<-rbind(TMP,DF) 
    } 
}
```

The result is

```
 str(DF)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ NAME: Factor w/ 1 level "BARNES & NOBLE": 1 1
```

I Hope this is what you're looking for?

All the best

Comment: Sorry. I get how to replace the &. Trying to figure out how to do so in an automated fashion that doesn't throw any warnings.

Comment: Hi @JJFord3 Could you post what you need to do? as opposed to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can pre-process or modify your data, try replacing the `&` with the following:

```
&amp;
```